# Проектирование базы данных с таблицами без первичного ключа

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, проектирование

Прежде всего вопрос к опытным коллегам : а допускаются ли таблицы без ПК(первичный ключ) в профессиональной БД? Ситуация такая - есть таблица *клиент* с разными полями в том числе ID(которое и есть пк для таблицы) но есть и таблица контактные данные (без пк) там столбцы состоят из (ID, phone, email, приоритетный способ связи и тд. другие способы) стоит ли устанавливать связь между этими таблицами и как если стоит? Ведь номеров может быть много и они могут добавляться.

Comment: Если ключа нет - создайте id для записи. Предположим вы случайно добавили для ID=1 один и тот же телефон 2 раза. И теперь хотите удалить одну из записей. Напишите delete который это сделает. `delete where id=1 and phone='123-45-67'` удалит обе записи, ведь они полностью одинаковы ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl;dr;

Да, добавляейте FK. Если у вас одна запись в таблице контактов для каждого кастомера - делаейте Id (CustomerID) в таблице контактов первичным ключем + кластерным индексом. Если больше одной для одного заказчика - добавляйте отдельную колонку CustomerDetailsID, и и делайте PK+CI ее + добавьте некластерный индекс по CustomerID.

Если email и предпочтительный способ контакта для клиента один, а телефонов - много - выносите телефоны в отдельную таблицу.

## Длинная версия

Ок, чтобы понять, допустимы ли таблицы без Primary Key, нужно сначала понять что такое PK и какое отношение он имеет к индексам.

Primary Key и Foreign Key - это, прежде всего, логические концепции.

PK - это такая колонка (или несколько колонок), которая однозначно идентифицирует запись. Т.е. одному значению PK соответствует одна запись в текущей таблице. Например, значение ID в таблице клиентов однозначно идентифицирует запись о клиенте в этой таблице.

FK - это колонка, каждому значению которой однозначно соответствует какая-то запись в другой таблице. Например, для каждого СustomerID в таблице контактных данных есть ровно одна запись в таблице Customers.

PK и FK - это свойства самой структуры данных. Чисто теоретически - неважно, поставили ли вы отметку PK на Customer.ID, и создали ли вы FK ContactDetails.CustomerID -> Customer.ID - колонки от этого не перестанут идентифицировать записи. Например, в базе данных Team Foundation Server вообще не проставлены FK - что не мешает ему вполне нормально работать :)

---

Зачем тогда ставить отметки PK и FK при создании базы в SQL Server?

- Это позволяет SQL Server жестко поддерживать уникальность, защищая вас от ошибок в данных. Т.е. он просто не даст вам вставить еще одну запись Customer с тем же ID. И не даст вписать в таблицу ContactDetails запись для несуществующего заказчика.
- Это позволяет SQL Server строить запросы более эффективно. Например, при поиске заказчика по ID он точно будет знать, что найдет не больше одной строки. А не, например, 100500 заказчиков с ID=1. И он выберет соответствующий план запроса, выделит соответствующее количество памяти под запрос и т.д.

---

Какое отношение это все имеет к индексам? Дело в том, что для поддержания целостности PK и FK SQL Server-у необходимы определенные физические структуры в базе данных.

В SQL Server есть два формата хранения таблицы

- Куча. Собственно, название говорит само за себя - это просто все строки таблицы, лежащие на диске в виде (гм) таблицы. Чтобы найти что-то в куче - вам придется перебрать всю кучу. Эта операция называется Table Scan, и она жутко неэффективна при большом количестве данных (она реально перебирает все данные, ставит на них локи, вобщем, в реальной системе обычно ничего хорошего она не несет)
- Кластерный индекс. Это дерево, построенное по какой-то колонке с уникальным значением (или нескольким колонкам), в листьях которого лежат сами строки таблицы. Кластерный индекс позволяет очень быстро искать данные по значению самой колонки.

---

Кроме кластерных индексов есть еще и некластерные - это точно такие же деревья поиска, но в листьях у них лежит значение кластерного индекса (или rowid из кучу). Т.е. они позволяют найти по какой-то колонке значение (например, дате регистрации) значение из кластерного индекса (по которому потом можно выбрать уже сами данные строки). Некластерный индекс может накладывать дополнительные ограничения - например, уникальность данных. Но тем не менее - сами данные он (по умолчанию) в себе не хранит.

---

Ок, как эти физические структуры соответствуют PK и FK?

Для PK нужна возможность быстро проверить существование и уникальность записи. Поэтому PK создается или на основе кластерного индекса, или на основе уникального некластерного индекса. Просто так висеть в воздухе он не может.

Типичным кандидатом на кластерный индекс является Primary Key - т.к. и значение кластерного индекса и значение PK должны быть уникальным, должны однозначно идентифицировать строку и т.д. - и в реальных схемах редко возникает ситуация, когда под эти требования попадает сразу две разных колонки.

Тот же Management Studio по одной кнопке создает одновременно и PK и Clustered Index. Поэтому кластерный индекс и Primary Key считаются чуть ли не синонимами. Хотя на самом деле есть техническая возможность создать кластерный индекс по одной колонке, а PK - по другой.

Для FK не нужна поддерживающая структура в той таблице, на которой он задан. Но ему нужна поддерживающая структура в той таблице, на которую он ссылается. Т.к. он должен проверять существование и уникальность, но только в другой таблице - то требования к этой стуктуре совпадают к требованиями к структуре PK в той таблице, на которую ссылается FK.

Например, при вставке в ContactDetails SQL Server должен проверять, что для вставляемого значения CustomerID есть соответствующая (и ровно одна!) запись в Customers. Поэтому для FK со стороны Customer нужен или кластерный индекс по той же колонке, или хотя бы уникальный ключ. В таблице ContactDetails при этом никаких структур данных ради этого FK не требуется.

Comment: " Но тем не менее - сами данные он (по умолчанию) в себе не хранит."
Как раз таки хранит. Некластерный индекс хранит в себе колонки, явно включенные в индекс (в основной список и в Include) и ключ кластерного индекса этой таблицы, либо RID, если таблица хранится кучей. Кластерный, соответственно, хранит все колонки таблицы, и, собственно, является главным местом хранения данных таблицы.

Comment: Во всем остальном - шикарный и максимально полный ответ.

Comment: @minamoto я пытался выразить это в "(по умолчанию)". попробую дописать в ответ в каком-то виде :)

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял, то тут имеется ввиду таблица без кластеризованного индекса.
Как правило такие таблицы называются кучами.
Их стоит использовать, например, в следующих случаях:

1) В таблице не будет много записей и нам, при обращении к таблице, нужно делать скан.

2) Если созданы некластеризованные индексы и доступ к данным осуществляется через них.

3) Когда мы знаем что в таблицу будет производиться массовая запись данных.

Есть и другие варианты использования куч. Все зависит от архитектуры проекта.В крупных проектах такое встречается довольно часто.

Более подробно можно почитать на [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com//library/hh213609.aspx).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60427/discussion-on-answer-by-------).

Answer (score 1):

> допускаются ли таблицы без ПК(первичный ключ) в профессиональной БД?

Первичный ключ в таблице нужен для того, чтобы можно было однозначно идентифицировать запись - например, при наличии в таблице полных дубликатов по остальным полям, или при использовании внешних ключей (связей) к этой таблице.

Если для данной конкретной таблицы ничего подобного не требуется, то наличие в ней первичного ключа необязательно. Некошерно, конечно, но и ничего особенно плохого в этом нет. Хотя системы зачастую развиваются, и в будущем такая необходимость может появиться - так что порой имеет смысл ввести в структуру синтетический первичный ключ просто "на всякий пожарный".

К слову, если Вы даже не создаёте первичного ключа, не факт, что его нет. СУБД вполне может ввести (и скорее всего введёт) в структуру скрытое и недоступное Вам поле, которое будет выполнять роль синтетического первичного ключа, идентифицирующего запись. Например, СУБД же надо как-то идентифицировать, какой записи таблицы соответствует запись в индексе...

> стоит ли устанавливать связь между этими таблицами

При создании такой связи средствами СУБД (созданием внешнего ключа) Вы переложите заботу по контролю целостности и непротиворечивости информации на плечи специально предназначенной для этого службы SQL-сервера. Это убережёт Вас от потенциального нарушения логической целостности данных, что в общем полезно - если не создавать такую связь и возложить эту задачу на клиентское ПО, которое гораздо хуже приспособлено для подобных функций, то можно поиметь ненужные проблемы, особенно в случае нештатных ситуаций. Так что если логика требует такой связи - её необходимо создать.